# Inaccurate MousePosition

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i'm doing something as simple as form.Location = MousePosition but i keep getting a somewhat constant point (300~,500~) even when i'm clicking something in the far right of a 1920x1080 screen... am i missing something here?

Comment: Are you trying to move your form around?  Maybe you could post your actual code...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the point back relative to some control (possibly the form itself) rather than the absolute position on the screen.

Without seeing your code I'm not going to be able to say exactly what's going on, but you need to see if you are calling [`PointToClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx), for example, on the cursor location.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for wasting your time, i forgot to set the form's StartPosition property to Manual...